# firing in a direction

Tags: python, pygame

I am having a problem getting my player to shoot in the direction the player is looking

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, (posx, posy), shell):
        'Called the Sprite class constructor'
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        'Save a reference to the screen'
        self.screen = screen
        self.shell = shell
        'Create the image for the sprite'
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player0.png")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        tranColor = self.image.get_at((1, 1))
        self.image.set_colorkey(tranColor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.charge = 50
        'Position the sprite'
        self.x = posx
        self.y = posy
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        self.velocity = Vectors.Vector2D(2, 2)

        self.imgDown = []
        self.imgRight = []
        self.imgLeft = []
        self.imgUp = []

        self.frame = 0
        self.delay = 3
        self.pause = self.delay
        self.speed = 5
def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.velocity.mulscaler(self.speed).x
            self.loadPicsLeft()
            self.calcDelay()
            self.image = self.imgLeft[self.frame]

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.centerx += self.velocity.mulscaler(self.speed).x
            self.loadPicsRight()
            self.calcDelay()
            self.image = self.imgRight[self.frame]


        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.centery -= self.velocity.mulscaler(self.speed).y
            self.loadPicsUp()
            self.calcDelay()
            self.image = self.imgUp[self.frame]

        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.centery += self.velocity.mulscaler(self.speed).y
            self.loadPics()
            self.calcDelay()
            self.image = self.imgDown[self.frame]

        if self.velocity.x > self.speed:
            self.velocity.x = self.speed
        if self.velocity.x < -self.speed:
            self.velocity.x = -self.speed

        if self.velocity.y > self.speed:
            self.velocity.y = self.speed
        if self.velocity.y < -self.speed:
            self.velocity.y = -self.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                self.shell.x = self.rect.centerx
                self.shell.y = self.rect.centery
                self.shell.speed = self.charge

    def calcDelay(self):
        self.pause -= 1
        if self.pause <= 0:
            self.pause = self.delay

            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 2:
                self.frame = 0

    def loadPics(self):
        for i in range (7):
            imgName = "player%d.png"% i
            tmpImg = pygame.image.load(imgName)
            tmpImg.convert()
            tranColor = tmpImg.get_at((0,0))
            tmpImg.set_colorkey(tranColor)
            self.imgDown.append(tmpImg)

    def loadPicsRight(self):
        for i in range (7):
            imgName = "playerRight%d.png"% i
            tmpImg = pygame.image.load(imgName)
            tmpImg.convert()
            tranColor = tmpImg.get_at((0,0))
            tmpImg.set_colorkey(tranColor)
            self.imgRight.append(tmpImg)

    def loadPicsLeft(self):
        for i in range (7):
            imgName = "playerLeft%d.png"% i
            tmpImg = pygame.image.load(imgName)
            tmpImg.convert()
            tranColor = tmpImg.get_at((0,0))
            tmpImg.set_colorkey(tranColor)
            self.imgLeft.append(tmpImg)

    def loadPicsUp(self):
        for i in range (7):
            imgName = "playerUp%d.png"% i
            tmpImg = pygame.image.load(imgName)
            tmpImg.convert()
            tranColor = tmpImg.get_at((0,0))
            tmpImg.set_colorkey(tranColor)
            self.imgUp.append(tmpImg)

class Shell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill((0xff, 0xff, 0xff))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0xff, 0xff, 0xff))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (0, 0, 0), (25, 25), 25)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (10, 10))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (-100, -100)

        self.speed = 0
        self.dir =0
        self.reset()

    def update(self):
        self.checkBounds()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def reset(self):
        """ move off stage and stop"""
        self.x = -100
        self.y = -100
        self.speed = 0
```

This is my player and my shell class, at the moment all my shell does is appear in the position of my player, what im looking for is my player to shoot the bullet to the right when he looks right, left when looking left etc. Can anyone offer me any tips on what i can do to achieve this. Im only beginning coding in college at the moment so i am struggling a bit

Comment: Where in the code do you store the orientation?

Comment: Well im not sure, i think it goes in the update method of the player, as in everytime i press space, the plyer will fire in that direction

Comment: You should be using `Shell.update` to move your bullets with its velocity. Not sure where you are moving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Store the direction of the player

2 - Make the velocity of the shell like so:

```
self.speedx = speed_length * cos(player.angle)
self.speedy = speed_length * sin(player.angle)
```

Note:

Speed_length is the total Euclidean distance travelled by the shell in one frame.

Angle **must be in radians or you can use degrees** if you do:

```
self.speedx = speed_length * cos(radians(player.angle))
self.speedy = speed_length * sin(radians(player.angle))
```